# Queryloader2 not working - TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to preload images with Queryloader2, but it doesn't seem to be working. It should be like [this](http://gayadesign.com/scripts/queryLoader2/). However, in my case it just loads the images like I didn't even include the library at all. It does give me 2 errors in the console of my browser:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < js/jquery.queryloader2.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'queryLoader2'
```

Where my full (non-functioning) code is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.queryloader2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").queryLoader2();
});
</script>


<img src="img/day1/3.jpg" alt=""/>
<img src="img/day1/3.jpg" alt=""/>
<img src="img/day1/3.jpg" alt=""/>

</body>
</html>
```

Why is this not working like it is supposed to? I'm 100% sure I'm linking to the right libraries. Thanks in advance.

Comment: trying to put all the files (to do a test) in the same directory

Comment: Tried that, did not work unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

Was pointing to a file with html markup inside, instead of javascript markup

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in Queryloader2 plugin with  tag. If you use any image as a background, it start to work but if there isn't any background images, it's not working.